# What should I do when a good Documentation change is rejected?

Tags: support, documentation, review-queues

In the `Getting started with Julia Language` topic, I proposed a change [in the discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/julia-lang/485/getting-started-with-julia-language/discussion). There was a pretty quick consensus that the (minor) edit was a good idea, and someone submitted a change. It was rejected by 3/5 reviewers as "too specific", even though the new text was more general than what it replaced.

What is the procedure for request a re-review? Should I just resubmit the change and hope for better luck?

I think it would be useful to be able to link a Discussion in a change to avoid rejections that miss the point of the change.

Also, while it's not relevant to this case, the change was submitted by someone whose top tag is `julia-lang`. It seems weird to me that none of the five reviewers even have `julia-lang` in their tag list, and that there isn't a clear way to escalate the change to people with experience in the language.

Comment: Well coming here is a good start.  If a gold or silver tag badge holder sees this and agrees they can insta-apply the edit instead of having it reviewed.

Comment: If I had to guess, one or two of the last reviewers saw the previous rejections and assumed the rejection was correct. Why the first rejecter decided to do so, I don't even have a guess.

Comment: To more easily find silver or gold badgers (or anyone who cares about the Docs in question), y'all might consider using or making a tag-specific chat room: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms By the way, you can link to a discussion, like http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/julia-lang/485/getting-started-with-julia-language/discussion?page=1&pagesize=30&tab=active&type=all#itemid=25&itemtype=general